# How do I show a temporary transitory message/notification after redirecting in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to show a temporary message right before I redirect using

```
$location.path("/customerList");
```

But persists the redirect and show for the same duration it would show as if I did not redirect.

Im using AngularJS 1.5.0 with bootstrap 3
The purpose is to allow the ability to change the view for the end user, but provide feedback on the operation that resulted in the redirect. "User XYZ Saved Successfully" , where XYZ could very well be some property of JSON returned from an API after saving.

The message needs to be dynamic when its shown.

Comment: What about using a service to set the msg, and getting the value on `ng-init` of the controller ? Did you try this approach ?

Comment: I was hoping for a reliable approach which explicitly is capable of showing messages after calling location.path()

Comment: Ok, and do you need to pass new msg everytime on location change ? Please elaborate

Comment: @ShashankVivek, per docs, "This directive (ng-init) can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses"

Comment: @ShashankVivek yes, dynamic message, updated question above

Comment: Can you comment on my answer and let me know if it helped ?

Comment: Hi @ShashankVivek, Ill check it out. Thank you.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you either mark it as an answer or let me know what more you want in it.

Answer (score 0):

how about using the events for $location ($locationChangeStart/$locationChangeSuccess) or using the below code

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function($event, next, current) { 
   // ... you could trigger something here ...
 });
```

Comment: Wouldnt this require me to define at Every controller? may violate DRY principle

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So here are my suggestions

1. [Check this plunkr (click on 'section 1' and then click the button which you'll see in that route)](https://plnkr.co/edit/1pk2UNKmLszYsHLFlUeU?p=preview). You cant pass a param using `$location` with a message because that would pollute your url. So, you can create a service to keep that data. Also, create a site level controller to handle site level logic.

app.js

```
app.controller('siteCtrl',function($rootScope,$scope,msgSvc,$timeout){

 $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function($event, next, current) { 
   var timer ;
    if(next.$$route.originalPath === '/two'){
      $scope.msg = msgSvc.getMsg();
      timer = $timeout(function(){
           $scope.msg = '';
           msgSvc.setMsg('');
      },2000);
    }
 });
})

function OneController($scope,$location,msgSvc){
    $scope.doSomething = function(){
      // set some msg and then go the route
        msgSvc.setMsg('Success navigation from Section 1');
        $location.path("/two");
    };
}
```

2. Create a component which can listen to this event, and displays accordingly.